# When a form is submitted I would like to do the following:

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Here is a little background to what I am doing currently. When a form is submitted I have code that is taking that data and putting it into a Google Doc template that I made. It is then taking that template and emailing it back to me as a PDF, then deleting the temp copy of the template. This is working well.

Now for what I would like to have it do instead. Instead of copying that data to a Google Doc, I would like to pull certain parts of that Google form submission and put them into a table on another tab. Then I would like to save a copy of that sheet (with a new name), then email the table in a pdf form. I do not even know if this is possible but any help at all would be appreciated.

Here is my current code for what I am doing now

```
function afterFormSubmit(e){
    const info = e.namedValues;
    const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
    const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange(entryRow, 7).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());

   GmailApp.sendEmail('xxx@xxxxxxx.com' + e.namedValues['Email Address'], "New Pay Sheet from Flores", "Please see the attached PDF for the newest pay sheet from Flores.", {
     attachments: [pdfFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     name: 'Flores Roofing'
   }); 

}



function createPDF(info){



const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder ID Here");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Temp Folder ID Here");
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("Template Doc ID here");

const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{Cname}", info['Customer Name (Located on the sub-contract)'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Add}", info['Customer Address (Located on the sub-contract)'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Work}", info['Was this a repair or a full roof replacement?'][0]);
body.replaceText("{PO}", info['Tear off and install squares'][0]);
openDoc.saveAndClose();




const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF); 
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Name'][0] + " " + "Pay Sheet");
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);

return pdfFile;
}
```